# Как найти сумму элементов под главной диагональю?

Tags: c++, математика, матрицы

Нужно найти сумму элементов под главной диагонали матрицы.
К примеру,дана матрица

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
2 4 3 2
5 6 7 8
```

Нужна сумма цифр 5,2,4,5,6,7.
Я написал программу для вычисления главной диагонали.
Вот код:

```
int main()
{
    int sizeN,sizeM;
    cin >> sizeN;
    sizeM = sizeN;
    
    int array[sizeN][sizeM] = {};
    int total = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeM; j++) {
            cin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    for (int i=0;i<sizeN;i++)
      for (int j=0;j<sizeM;j++)
          if (i==j){
              total+=array[i][j];
          } 
          
    cout << total;

    return 0;
}
```

Как вычислить сумму цифр под диагональю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было просто заменить условие во втором цикле j<i:

```
for (int i=0;i<sizeN;i++){
          for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
                  total = total + array[i][j];
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте библиотеку FNL - https://fnl-library.tk/ , она вам поможет выполнить задачу.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]